How do I clear the cache by key in fastapi-cache?
I didn't find in the fastapi-cache documentation how to clear the cache for a specific key. Could you please advise how to do this? I haven't overridden the key builder.
config
from fastapi_cache import FastAPICache
from fastapi_cache.backends.redis import RedisBackend
from redis import asyncio as aioredis

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI) -> AsyncIterator[None]:
    # Startup
    redis = aioredis.from_url(str(settings.REDIS_URL))
    FastAPICache.init(RedisBackend(redis), prefix="fastapi-cache")
    yield
    # Shutdown

@router.get("/{referer_id}/referrals")
@cache(expire=60)
async def get_refferals(db_session: SessionDep, referer_id: int):
    return await get_referred_users_by_referer_id(
        db_session=db_session, referer_id=referer_id
    )


@auth_router.post("/signup")
async def signup(db_session: SessionDep, user_in: UserCreate) -> Any:
    The logic here involves creating a user,
    and if they use a referral code from a specific person
    (for example, they use the referral code of the user with id 5),
    then the cache related to the endpoint GET /{referer_id(5)}/referrals should be cleared.

    return user

I tried using FastAPICache.clear, but it doesn't work. Could the problem be with the keys?

Hi! Please update your question to a minimal reproducible example. Right now it's unclear what library you are using, and how it's configured.

@M.O. hi! I use the fastapi-cache library and added all the configuration I have

Yeah, FastAPICache.clear should be the solution, how did you vompute the key?
